# Learn Python the hard way Ex39, having a hard time understanding its code

Tags: python, hash

I'm having a hard time understanding a lot of the code in [Learn Python The Hard Way Ex39](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html).

My first confusion is regarding why the author used modular division here `hash(key) % len(aMap)`. What value does it return? Why does author need the reminders?

```
def hash_key(aMap, key):
    """Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to an index for the aMap's buckets."""
    return hash(key) % len(aMap)
```

The second confusing thing to me is the next code

```
def get_bucket(aMap, key):
    """Given a key, find the bucket where it would go."""
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]
```

In my understanding, `bucket_id` should be equal to the value of `hash(key) % len(aMap)` so why don't we just return `aMap[hash(key)]`?

Comment: Maybe the fact of understanding the idea of [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) using buckets could be  useful first

Answer (score 0):

Modulo is used to constrain a number to a range. This is a well known trick. That way if you overflow you "send" the number back to the range.

Suppose I want a number in [0, 9) and I have a hash generator than generates numbers in the range [0, 100). If I use `hash % 10` it is guaranteed to be in my expected range. In the first piece of code the trick is used to match an item with a bucket, since hashes not necessarily limited but buckets are.

The second piece of code just fetches the bucket with the constrained hash (in bucket range). To understand it you must understand that a hash map most of the times works with buckets. A **good** hash map distributes items across the buckets equally (or close to it).

So if we re-iterate - if you have hashes in the range [0, 100) and 10 buckets [0, 10), the bucket index for each item could be calculated with `hash % 10`. This would match each item's hash to a bucket in the wanted range [0, 10).