# indexing a dictionary with key hash values

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I am currently going through learn python the hard way, and i find my self stuck on this dictionary exercise: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

What gives me problems is the following code:

```
def hash_key(aMap, key):
    """Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to
    an index for the aMap's buckets."""
    return hash(key) % len(aMap)
```

How can i be sure that i wont get duplicate values from the hash_key function? Since modulo is being used, what prevents hash() from returning values such that after modulo is used on them they return the same hash_key.

Ex. `len(aMap)=10`, `hash(key1) = 20`, `hash(key2) = 30`, therefore `hash_key` for both dict keys is 0, even though they are obviously not equal.

I'm having trouble grasping the concepts behind hashing, so if you have any reading material suitable for my skill level, please share. I'm not afraid to work hard.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hash functions are not supposed to be unique. That's why you use "buckets". Each hash value has its own bucket of items. I've answered something very similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124402/learn-python-the-hard-way-ex39-having-a-hard-time-understanding-its-code/34124455#34124455

Answer (score 1):

The hashmap, as proposed in the linked exercise, *intends* to generate key-collisions.

The data structure is a list of lists, where the key's hash-modulus value determines the 2nd-level list where your data goes.

Imagine the structure as an array of `n` buckets, each with its own `key`. If you put something into this datastructure, the `hash_key()` method finds the *appropriate* bucket and appends your new data to that bucket's contents. Actually, it is random what bucket will receive your data, but since it's a hash function, it will always be the same bucket for the same key.

Comment: I get the part with the same keys ending up in the same bucket. It was different keys ending in the same bucket that troubled me. But if i understood correctly from your and @ReutSharabani 's answer, that is completely ok. I guess that doesnt happen that often, and even with that Search time is still low.

Comment: It happens more or less often depending on your amount of buckets. And you are right: It is absolutely okay, since it is meant to happen. It is just some kind of very random data partitioning. Real hash maps use more elaborate methods that take care of 'buckets' being filled regularly and search/insert methods remaining time constant.